# How to change SelectDocument.cs object Value on Kentico

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

How to change the Object Value on `SelectDocument.cs` 
I want it to filter by `ForeignKey` Value not by `GUID`

```
public override object Value
{
    get
    {
        return txtGuid.Text.Trim();
    }
    set
    {
     //value = GUID 
        if (value != null)
        {
           //When i debug and load the form page value is set to GUID how to query and change it to foreign key.
            txtGuid.Text = value.ToString();
            SetAliasPath(value, FieldIsInteger());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi there, I just wanted to be sure I've understood that you are asking - you want to be able to return the `ForeignKey` value for a document from the document selector control.  I assume that this is to allow you to identify the page type specific data in fewer DB queries, is that the case?

Comment: Hi mnield, Thank you for your response. I am asking if we can replace the value from guid to nodealias path. thanks